# How to make Image behave as a button on click?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

My html code is

```
<div align="center">
          <div class="buttonwrap"><div class="imgtext">Renew Your Policy</div></div>  
       </div>
```

i want this image show as a button on click on it.can any one help me to make its look and feel as a button when click on it..Please help me..
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can make a real Button width an Image as Background with CSS

```
input.button {
    background: url('path_to_your_image') o o no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 500px;
}

<input type="button" class="button" onclick="your_function();" />
```

or

```
<input type="submit" class="button" onclick="your_function();" />
```

Or you can do

```
<img src="path_to_your_image" onclick="your_function();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.buttonwrap {
  border: 3px outset gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.buttonwrap:active {
  border-style: inset;
}
```

But the buttonwrap div should really be an `A`, and you can't put a `DIV` in an `A` so change imgtext to a `SPAN` (or just get rid of it).

Comment: No i want image behave as a button.Don't want to use image in button background.

Comment: Why "no"? This will work just fine with an image as well, and it doesn't have to be in the background, just put the image in the `A`.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by A?

Comment: @EktaShukla The `A` tag: `<A href="...">...</A>`

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ekta are you looking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/XOblz5U7

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Define the background image in `.button` background

**HTML**

```
<div align="center">
  <div class="buttonwrap"><div class="imgtext"><input type="button" class="button" value="Renew Your Policy"/></div></div>  
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
background:red;
width:150px;
height:50px;
}
```

SEE THE UPDATED DEMO :- http://tinkerbin.com/E30xfTi8

Comment: yes but how will i make it? can you send me its css because i dont want to use button..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `<button>` then?

```
<div align="center">
  <button class="buttonwrap">
        <span class="imgtext">Renew Your Policy</span>
  </button>  
</div>
```

You can mess around with the padding, border, background color and all that, but this is the mosst basic setups for creating button-like behavior. Just make it into a real button.

Comment: no because image is not fit to that button..so i have to make image behave as a button

Comment: You can add images in a <button>. Think of it as a div that acts like a button. If that's not working for you, could you please post an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more style to Ariel's answer:

```
.buttonwrap {
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 3px outset gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.buttonwrap:active {
  border-style: inset;
}
```

Comment: can i use any other thing on active mode in place of border-style:inset..it showing as a border..which s not looking good becaouse i am clicking on image..

Comment: @EktaShukla What do you mean by "act like a button"?

Comment: means when i click on it it goes inside like in the button means on clicking it give feel as a button..when i am using border style inset it showing as a button but inset border is alos showing which i dont want.

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qCpKt/ (inspired by: http://designshack.net/articles/css/6-useful-css-button-recipes-you-can-copy-paste/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make like this. use map tag 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

`enter code here`

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```